# Sending in a prop object where some are dependant on a boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component taking in the prop `data`.

```
<Button
    data={booleanValue && {
        d: 4,
        // another 8 key/values
    }}
/>
```

So data value only gets passed in if `booleanValue` is true.

But I also have another 3 more value which I wish to add inside this data which are meant to always show.
So show irregardless of whether booleanValue is true or false.

Is there a way I could write this elegantly within the component above itself?

I could create the object separately like following which would work.
But trying to see if I could achieve it without additional object creation.

One possible solution but don't want to create an object like this.

```
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
};

if (booleanValue) {
    obj['d'] = 4;
    // more values being added same way.
}

<Button
    data={obj}
/>
```